# React Hook Form useFieldArray .map not returning any elements/display

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Please help, it's my first time to use useFieldArray and I can't seem to find any issue with my usage alongside with useFormContext. The main issue is that elements are not displaying after the field.map of useFieldArray but I have no any error on my code. I even tried using the exact codes from the example from the [document](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray) but still same issue.

react-hook-form version: 7.27.1

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you rendering anything inside the divs that are not visible?

Comment: What part of you code is not visible/displaying?

Comment: everything that is inside the fields.map. I really can't figured out why.

Comment: @ShubhamWaje I misunderstood your first question. Yes, I'm rendering text fields inside those divs but they are not visible/displaying.

Comment: even the text in line 59 is not visible.

Comment: I finally figured it out. I was thinking it will display blank fields on first render. useFieldArray will not display anything unless you append or set default values. In my case, I did not set the default values of my child components.